# Want to make two python lists have the same choice be chosen using random.choice()

Tags: python, list, game-development

I am trying to make a Pokemon guesser game, where the names of the pokemon are stored in a list, and their types are stored in another list, as seen below:

```
gen1 = ["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander ", "Charmeleon", "Charizard", "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree", "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill", "Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot", "Rattata", "Raticate", "Spearow", "Fearow", "Ekans", "Arbok", "Pikachu", "Raichu", "Sandshrew", "Sandslash", "Nidoran♀", "Nidorina", "Nidoqueen", "Nidoran♂", "Nidorino", "Nidoking", "Clefairy", "Clefable", "Vulpix", "Ninetales"]
gen1types = ["grass", "grass", "grass", "fire ", "fire", "fire/dragon", "water", "water", "water", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "flying", "flying", "flying", "normal", "normal", "flying", "flying", "poison", "poison", "electric", "electric", "ground", "ground", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "fairy", "fairy", "fire", "fire"]
```

I want it to be so when a random pokemon is chosen from list gen1, the matching type is chosen along with it, for example if Bulbasaur is chosen, the matching type of that would be grass, I have written their types in the same order the pokemon are written, but I cannot get the correct type to match with the pokemon that is randomly chosen.. I tried to use gen1.index() but I would get an errors or the wrong type would be chosen. Can anyone help me with this?
here is my full code so far:

```
import random
life = 4

genone = ["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander ", "Charmeleon", "Charizard", "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree", "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill", "Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot", "Rattata", "Raticate", "Spearow", "Fearow", "Ekans", "Arbok", "Pikachu", "Raichu", "Sandshrew", "Sandslash", "Nidoran♀", "Nidorina", "Nidoqueen", "Nidoran♂", "Nidorino", "Nidoking", "Clefairy", "Clefable", "Vulpix", "Ninetales"]
genonetypes = ["grass", "grass", "grass", "fire ", "fire", "fire/dragon", "water", "water", "water", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "flying", "flying", "flying", "normal", "normal", "flying", "flying", "poison", "poison", "electric", "electric", "ground", "ground", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "fairy", "fairy", "fire", "fire"]
genone[0,1] = genonetypes[]
x = random.choice(genone)
.index(str(x))y = random.choice(genonetypes)
print(y)
print(str("The pokemon type is " + y))
userin = input("enter they pokemon you think it is: ")
if userin == x:
  print("yes")
```

Comment: the code you posted can't be executed

Comment: It would probably be better to store the names and types together, for example in a dict `{"Bulbasaur": 'grass', ...}` or a list of tuples `[("Bulbasaur", 'grass'), ...` or objects. This would make the problem behind your question disappear, and could prevent a maintenance nightmare to come...

Answer (score 0):

Just get the random number of the index, something like :

```
idx = random.randint(0, len(genone))
pokemon      = genone[idx]
pokemon_type = genonetypes[idx]
```

Alternatively, instead of two lists, I would use a dictionary to associate a pokemon to its element :

```
pokemons = {
  'Bulbasaur' : 'grass',
  'Charmander': 'fire',
  #...
}
```

And then pick one entry randomly :

```
random.choice(list(pokemons.items()))
```

Yields :

```
('Charmander', 'fire')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is what you need. It pairs up corresponding elements from 2 (or more) iterables, allowing you to get a pair via `random.choice`.

```
import random
life = 4

genone = ["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander ", "Charmeleon", "Charizard", "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree", "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill", "Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot", "Rattata", "Raticate", "Spearow", "Fearow", "Ekans", "Arbok", "Pikachu", "Raichu", "Sandshrew", "Sandslash", "Nidoran♀", "Nidorina", "Nidoqueen", "Nidoran♂", "Nidorino", "Nidoking", "Clefairy", "Clefable", "Vulpix", "Ninetales"]
genonetypes = ["grass", "grass", "grass", "fire ", "fire", "fire/dragon", "water", "water", "water", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "flying", "flying", "flying", "normal", "normal", "flying", "flying", "poison", "poison", "electric", "electric", "ground", "ground", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "fairy", "fairy", "fire", "fire"]
x, y = random.choice(list(zip(genone,genonetypes)))
# print(y)
print(str("The pokemon type is " + y))
userin = input("enter they pokemon you think it is: ")
if userin == x:
  print("yes")
```

The `list()` is needed as `zip` only returns an iterator, which doesn't work as an input to `random.choice` since `random.choice` needs to be able to take the length of the input.

Answer (score 0):

`index` works fine:

```
x = random.choice(genone)
y = genonetypes[genone.index(x)]
print(x, y)
```

Though it's more efficient to get a random index and use it for both lists:

```
i = random.randrange(len(genone))
x = genone[i]
y = genonetypes[i]
print(x, y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZOxbtswEIZ3PYXgyQaCdOjSJUMcNEARpCgSIB0MD2fpLB1Ek8yJrKVMQd6ir9cXcY@kJduJhwwCv5@6O5L/kbZ3tdFfv1ne7WhjDbucQZdmk2UVaqMxv8oXk7lXK2jB8@Qin/z40w/4hNoPfFMDbyQVOR8lKjR6UPQCXAbx@OyJncLAv4GdGcRcQesMtVHcgEO2FPkeHVgTk@feyfyaMaUjlin3DhqvIUbIHJNSgX9RWWE/knHOHImAD@AcONgjFbJq3KNFYLMNeDvS9wZ0G@CaV6ZJhRooap@yaU@P4kJbM25HIeeqg/hJpRF7//19HRWlTQd@9oj6JOztKMwM3JCuokEK10Dcj7xKTjx5ZalL0VqMU9hOlvtuut5iG1taMbTxLB9hTYz5AMP4pWSoUjO3oTPnYeWrTw5r1e/PcY60kbukTulcnJXbkjZ1ILl0hWMq3nPFxuvylM7lf5ZG8w9w5JdYnnXidHpNl0VtqMBp6sIs6@XPUUcWiS9Jnk837WbLzErH3bS7yPtZltGhThjkq3CqUA/lZnGlJBa0/FCdTurtdv8B)